# Something causing horizontal scrolling on IE9 and Opera

Tags: css, facebook-like, internet-explorer-9, opera

I'm developing the front-end portion of this site: http://oq.totaleclips.com

When I look at one of the movie listings, like http://oq.totaleclips.com/mpa/The_Hunger_Games_(Movie_2012), I get a horizontal scroll on Opera and Internet Explorer 9. If I put `body {overflow-x:hidden} in my CSS, I get an expected result, but then Facebook Like is cut off when a user pushes the Like button and is prompted for a comment... it's going to make it harder to "Like" on Facebook.

Is this a Facebook issue, and Opera issue, or both? I cannot find a DOM element that is causing the overflow, and I suppose it could be the Facebook Like iFrame "reserving" the space to the right of the Like button, but I don't want to assume that. The Facebook button doesn't even seem to work in Opera, but that's a side issue.

I've been developing using Firefox and Chrome, with limited access to IE9, so it was disappointing to discover the horizontal scroll when I looked at it from a Windows computer. Then, to see that Opera does the same thing, I can hardly be mad at IE9. And, moving the Facebook Like button to the left causes a undesired line-break between it and the social buttons that follow.

What is causing the overflow / horizontal scroll, and how could I discover issues like this on my own?

Editing for specificity: The horizontal scrollbar, when scrolled right, reveals a white column on the far right of the screen layout. This does go away when the browser window is resized horizontally, but it does not show up in the DOM. Elements on the page inside the body are not seen to flow into the white space on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot find a DOM element that is causing the overflow

Here’s your culprit:

```
.screener .content {
    margin: auto;
    width: 61em;
}
```

Maybe `61em` are just a little much … depending on font-size and available window/tab width.

Comment: I'm not wholly convinced. If I reduce that size, the contents collapse , which to me says the size is perfectly fitted to the actual contents (player + sidebar).  Also, there are no DOM elements that are seen to flow into that space. I would expect to see some spilling into the white right side when Inspected if the size was really the issue. I would also expect the margins to fill in with the background color if it were just a width issue on a certain div. I'm still open to working around this but 61em isn't so wide, is it?

Comment: Give that element a bright red border as well, and you’ll see how far it stretches. But maybe that’s only part of the problem, because you have layered elements with the class `.content` into each other, and they are all getting affected by this rule in your stylesheet. See to it, that you’ll target only the outermost div.content element with your rule that you’re setting the width with (and not all those elements with the same class inside of it), then it should fit.